# Groovy DSLD and ServiceLoader pattern

Tags: eclipse, groovy, dsld

I have in my Groovy scripts an implicit variable, "services", whose role is to lookup services in a registry.

I can call it with the following syntaxe :

```
def myService = services.lookup 'com.test.MyService'
```

The implementation of the lookup method doesn't return an instance of MyService, but a special GroovyObject which delegate missing methods to the service.

I want to tell Eclipse that calls to myService should be delegated to MyService, in order to add to the autocompletion list all methods from MyService. However, I didn't success to implements it with a DSLD definition.

Is it possible to implement such behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used two contributions :

- The first one discover every call to services.lookup and populates a map in wormhole
- The second one declare every properties in the wormhole map as a global property

A simplified version :

```
contribute(isMyDSL() & currentType('ServiceProxy') & bind(exprs: assignedVariable(currentType()))) {
      def name = exprs[0].leftExpression.name
      def classType - exprs[0].arguments.getExpression(0).text /* Introspecting MethodCall */

      def services = wormhole.services
      if (!services) {
        services = [:]
        wormhole.services = services
      }
      services[name] = classType
}

contribute(isMyDSL() & isThisType()) {
      wormhole.properties?.each { name, type -> 
        property name:name, type:type, doc:"OSGI Service: ${type}"
      }
}
```